# BNE - I type instruction - Where does 'i' come into play?

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to understand assembly a little better, and I am not really sure how the `i` (immediate) comes into play for `BNE`. Please forgive the noobness.

If `BNE` writes like this:

```
BNE $1, $2, loop
```

which means "goto loop if `$1` does not equal `$2`" then I am assuming that the loop is the immediate part. Correct?

Is this just a program counter or a location of the loop? So, if the loop was set at some instruction count (let's just call it `0x0001`), would this loop address (or instruction count) be set in this `i`?

Maybe it would be better if I wrote it out like this...

```
opcode  = 5 | reg1 = whatever addr | reg2  = whatever addr | immediate = 0x0001
```

Does that look right, or am I just really confused?

Comment: Quoting `MIPS32TM Architecture For Programmers Volume II: The MIPS32TM Instruction Set`, `BNE: An 18-bit signed offset (the 16-bit offset field shifted left 2 bits) is added to the address of the instruction following the branch (not the branch itself), in the branch delay slot, to form a PC-relative effective target address. If the contents of GPR rs and GPR rt are not equal, branch to the effective target address after the instruction in the delay slot is executed.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the assembler takes the address loop (that is really what it is a name for some address somewhere) it does the work for you to compute the offset, and encodes that offset into the instruction for you.  Otherwise you would have to say bne $1, $2, +28, hand computed number and then every time you modify your code between these two points you would have to re-adjust every one of these offsets.

Some assemblers or linkers actually, may go so far as to add a trampoline for you.  Say for example you have some instruction set that the relative jump is only 128 instructions, and you use a label that is not defined in that object.  The assembler might be so kind as to place an unconditional branch within 128 instructions to the place you really wanted to go.  some might not and you end up with an error that it cannot encode the offset in the instruction you asked for.

where I am headed is that you program with labels (addresses) and let the assembler do some of the work for you.  As in this case it converts the label you have to a distance from the current instruction and encodes that.

Comment: And as EOF pointed out in the comment.  This is documented, you need to look at instruction set documentation before asking questions like this.  Then if still confused then ask "the docs say this but I dont understand something"...

Comment: I had looked over the documentation, but it was getting very dry and a little confusing. Thank you for taking the time to answer. =)

Comment: re-reading my answer I think I could have written it better, but if you understood it that is all that matters...